# Time complexity of two implementations of x ** n

Tags: python, recursion, time

In Python, to practice recursion, I wrote these two functions to compute `x ** n`. They both return identical results, but one takes twice as long.

```
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n == 1:
            return x
        if n == -1:
            return 1/x

        if n % 2 == 0:
            ## even
            return self.myPow(x * x, n / 2)
        else:
            if n > 0:
                return x * self.myPow(  x * x, (n-1)/2)
            else:
                return 1/x * self.myPow(x * x, (n+1) / 2 )


class Solution2(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """

        ## Base cases
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n == 1:
            return x

        t = self.myPow(x, abs(n) // 2)

        if n > 0:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                return t * t
            else:
                return x * t * t
        else:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                return 1 / (t * t)
            else:
                return 1 / (x * t * t)
```

I used `cProfile` to time these two functions, but the one associated with `Solution()` takes twice as long as the one associated with `Solution2()`. Theoretically, they should both take `O(log n)`. May I know what's going on?

Comment: Keep in mind that if algorithm A takes 5logN time and B takes 10logN time, they are both O(logn)

Comment: Could you explain more and turn it into an answer? Thank you!

Comment: `Solution` is converting the exponent to a `float`, by using floating point division, while `Solution2` is using an integer exponent, by using integer division.  Why wouldn't you keep the exponent as an integer?  Seems like a bug in `Solution` which could make it run slower.  Try changing the `//` to `/` and see if it speeds up.

Comment: For completeness, you should also write a purely iterative version (using integer exponents), and note how much faster it is than your recursive versions.  Integer exponentiation is an inherently iterative problem, so an iterative version should be significantly faster.  The best way to learn about recursion is to apply it to a problem that actually benefits from it (i.e, one that would otherwise require an explicit stack).

Comment: The Big O notation is intended to show the growth ceiling of a function when its input grows infinitely. Therefore, there can be two functions that have the same growth pattern, but one is 2 times faster than the other. Like @GeorgeMenoutis  example.

Comment: Right.  Big O doesn't tell you whether one algorithm is faster than another in absolute terms.  Big O tells you "if I run this same code with 10x as much data, or 100x as much data, how much longer will it take than with 1x?"  That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are already multiple explanations around the internet, I'll put a light-on-the-maths view on the matter of big O notation.

Big O notation only cares how the algorithm will work when the data are *many*. And in order to say this without equations, "many" here means "so many that multiplicative constants don't matter".

Example: The simple algorithm to calculate matrix multiplication is O(N^3).
Let's say algorithm A1 take actually 1N^3, and A2 takes 100N^3. You might think 100x times faster is impressive, and it probably is - but big O notation is only about what happens "near the infinite". So, consider N=10^100. A1 will take 10^300, and A2 will take 10^302. Big deal, not much of difference, right? But consider an algorithm A3 which is , say , 5000N^2. Despite the large constant, it will come to 5*10^203, which IS a big difference. So near the infinite, only the "function" matters, and not the constants.

It is important to note that while big O does not care for constants, a well rounded programmer will. Choosing the best algorithm for an expected data size is NOT equivalent to just choosing the one with the smallest big-O. You have to know what a tool does in order to do the job right.